# Xamarin.android project build error in xamarin forms project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have tried to resolve fallowing error but not luck, What my issue is while build xamarin.android project shows 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added :Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/Accessibility
ServiceInfoCompat' error. I have search the cause of this error, many solutions are said that duplicate library files exist in our project i.e "xamarin.android.support.v4 and xamarin.android.support.v7". If I have remove any one of this again I am getting build faileds. If I have remove 'xamarin.android.support.v4' shows "view.pager" not found error and if I have remove 'xamarin.android.support.v7' getting lot of errors. Please suggest any idea to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.
'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earlier I faced the same issue, I had done these steps to solve it

1) First check the Target Framework i.e Mono Android it should be version more than 7.0 ,if it is not available in the properties. Update your Android SDK manager then you can set to v7.0

2)Uninstall the Xamarin.Forms packages and support files and Reinstall all with latest version